# Hue function for negative arguments

Tags: graphics

I want to use `Hue` function for different colours with the argument being a function, i.e.,

```
Hue[f[i,j]]
```

Now, `f[i,j]` in my case can take negative values. The range of my function is `[-2,2]` (which can be rescaled to `[-1,1]` if necessary, by dividing the function by 2). The problem is that `Hue` automatically rescales its argument to put it into the range of `[0,1)`. This is a problem for me as it will then show the same colour when my function is either `-1` or `0` or `1`, for example.
The actual figure I want to work on can be generated by the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
n := 10; 
angles = Table[RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}], {i, n}, {j, n}]; 
f[here_, down_, right_] := Cos[down - here] + Cos[right - here] 
g[list_, {i_, j_}] := Module[{m, n}, {m, n} = Dimensions[list]; {list[[i, j]], 
    If[i != m, list[[i + 1, j]], -list[[1, j]]], 
      If[j != n, list[[i, j + 1]], -list[[i, 1]]]}] 
GraphicsGrid[ MapIndexed[ Graphics[{LightGray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
    Hue[Rescale[f @@ g[angles, #2], {-2, 2}, {-1, 1}]], Thin, 
      Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}]}] &, angles, {2}]]
```

Comment: Why you dont you use `Rescale` like `Rescale[..,{-2,2},{0,1}]`? `Hue` will use the values of its first argument cyclically if they are outside the range $(0,1)$.

Comment: To rephrase @Spawn's comment: `Hue[]` is a *periodic function* with period $1$, with the colors determined by the usual color wheel. Use `Rescale[]` if you want to use `Hue[]` for your desired range, with the caveat that due to the periodicity, `Hue[0]` and `Hue[1]` are both `Red` (`RGBColor[1, 0, 0]`).

Answer (score 2):

`Hue` does not rescale its argument, but it is a periodic function, equivalent to `Hue[Mod[x, 1]]`.  What you need is rescaling: `Rescale[f[...], {-2,2}]`.